# split screens in 2.8

Tags: interface

Sorry for being so simple but i'm finding it really difficult to work out how to split screens and then rejoin them.

so i grab the corner of a screen and drag it creates a new screen then i grab the corner again and sometimes it creates a new one and sometimes it merges them.

I'm a bit confused about the controls.

I looked on the 2.8 manual and I think its a bit out of date as it looks the same as 2.79.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Click between them (on the separator) and you will have option to split or join. For doing it with corners just hold your mouse button and move it up or down.

Comment: Update: There is something fishy going on there. It seems like some spots are making new areas and other ones triggers arrows to join. Have no idea what going on there. As I can't find any particular pattern.

Answer (score 16):

It is the same as in 2.79 only the corners now look different - if you click on a corner of one area and then start dragging it in the direction of itself then it splits, if you start dragging it in the direction of another area it joins them. I believe the design for these functions might still be worked on and I would not be surprised if it was made a bit more intuitive in the end.

You can also rightclick on the edge between two areas and choose Join.

[image]

Comment: Why does it work once then the next time doing exactly the same motion it divides again. I cannot differentiate what motion I have to do to have a specific outcome. Then I have dozens of windows on my project.

Comment: Please see the updated answer with a gif. Also reread the old part: "...if you click on a corner of one area and then start dragging it in the direction of itself then it splits, if you start dragging it in the direction of another area it joins them."  It matters which side of the corner you click on - both areas have their side. The distance is quite small.

Comment: @EricHuelin +1 it's ununderstandable, very bad interface -1 for blender, the 2.7 was fin; they wantes to change everything, it's bad, bad, bad !

Comment: @Entretoize, I think this should not be a problem once you spend some time working with 2.8 versions. The frustration should go away once you get used to it. I really think there are some areas in Blender's UI, that are far from perfect, but come on... the corners are OK.

Comment: I still don't see a pattern how the corners splits or joins areas. When I try the exact same move multiple times and cancel with ESC it seems choose at random.

Comment: Now I got it! You have to grab the corner on the other half of the corner to join two areas and on same half if you want to split the area.