# How to show Preview Areas

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor, video

I accidentaly clicked join areas. How to show it?

[image: Screenshow]

[image: Preview]

Comment: Hello could you please elaborate a bit? Do you mean that you want to open a window again? You just need to put your cursor at one of the 4 corners of your window and left click drag?

Comment: Here is a example of moonboots' suggestion: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120891/split-screens-in-2-8 and here is shown how to choose/restore the editor for the area: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/177296/107598

Comment: Two more options if the UI is messed up completely: restore the workspace (add+delete) -or- save blend file and prevent Load UI: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94308/blender-viewport-and-workspace-reset